# How to use py2app for mac

Tags: python, py2app

Typing in the command in the terminal `python3 setup.py py2app` will bundle the python code.

I am having trouble on how to organize my python source code so that **py2app** can bundle many files together.

So how would I organize this to make a stand alone app using **py2app**??

[image: The picture of my folder and it's internals]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems are you facing? Have you read https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/tutorial.html  ?

Comment: thanks man. I just made it work. I had to fix the setup.py file. I think I am now having problems with not all the library is importing.

Comment: You are welcome. It is always a good practice to provide as much information in your question. If you have a new question then please ask a new question. :)

Comment: the command $python setup.py py2app will then compile it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are facing trouble packing all the files. You will have to use py2applet to create the setup and include all the files as arguments.

So presuming you have music.wav and Tetris.py, you should do this

```
$ py2applet --make-setup Tetris.py music.wav
```

Comment: py2applet should be the one that you should be using. Did you install py2app using "sudo pip install py2app" ?

Comment: Yeah okay cool thanks. I downloaded a PDF of the tutorial. It was too verbose for me. I am spending my break learning about these things. It is more fun then my Computer Science course in college where we spend months learning about graphs and Java and operating systems, etc.